# Set a Unix timestamp using Mongo's internal clock

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I would like to be able to set a timestamp on a field in Mongo as an integer in seconds, not milliseconds as is the default in Mongo from a node.js application. If I were to do that the following, is the new Date() calculated from my node application or by the Mongo database?

`db.testcollection.save({"mydate": Math.floor((new Date()).getTime()/1000)})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its depends where do you execute your code:

If you execute it **through a mongodb driver (e.g. a node application)** than the date object and further iterations are executed by the js runtime and then interpreted by mongodb, so if you execute:

`db.testcollection.save({"mydate": Math.floor((new Date()).getTime()/1000)})`

In a node application `Math.floor((new Date()).getTime()/1000)` is computed first by javascript, then this will be executed:

`db.testcollection.save({"mydate": 1568478964})`

A document will be created and `mydate` will be saved as integer